# Trouble with x64 application uninstalling

Tags: process, nsis, uninstallation

When I run uninstaller I want to check if application is running. I use FindProcDLL plug-in.

```
Function un.onInit
    FindProcDLL::FindProc "${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    IntCmp $R0 1 0 notRunning
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "${PRODUCT_NAME} is running. Please close it first" /SD IDOK
    Quit
notRunning:
FunctionEnd
```

This script work if application was build in x86 platform, but dont't work if application was build in x64 platform.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the (official) FindProc plugin is missing some 64bit support.

However, I have found an interesting post [NSIS installer for 64-bit Windows](http://bojan-komazec.blogspot.com/2011/10/nsis-installer-for-64-bit-windows.html) that refers to a [NSIS forum post](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=322583) adressing that issue. It mentions a version of FindProc that could work in your case.